# Information API Youtube

Tags: youtube-api

Good morning,

Recently I've been watching the YouTube API and have not found any information about the collection of data from a youtube account.

I have a Youtube channel and would like more information about users who subscribe to it, I also have a website where users are registered and need to know if the user is registered follower of my Youtube channel, I can only guess identify the user by email. So my question is whether it is possible by Youtube API or any other method of identifying this person and know if follower.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the list of activities in the Youtube API V3 you can obtain the activities of a particular user in a channel, specifying "channelId"  parameter and "mine" parameter for the user logged.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities

In case that the list of activities returns  videos as items you can get the channel id from the snippet of the video

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/

For this solution the user must be authenticated and give permissions to the application to access their data in youtube

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,

As you said, there isn`t option get the email of the user who is subscribed to my youtube channel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606101/how-to-get-user-email-from-google-plus-oauth

Comment: For this the user must be authenticated in multiple scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449544/multiple-scope-values-to-oauth2