# How to set multiple Oauth2 scopes in Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, postman, google-oauth, scopes

I'm trying to retrieve a course work for a course using the Google Classroom API. For this it's required multiple scopes. I can get this working from Java so I believe the list of scopes is correct. However, when trying from Postman, I get a 403 "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." error, which makes me think perhaps the way I'm adding the scopes together may not be correct. I've already tried using "+", ",", ";" and also spaces but none of them got rid of the error. Any ideas about what I may be missing please?

[image]

Thank you.

**Update**

Showing the Postman console which seems to identify only one scope for the request.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: try separating them with space and not returns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Scope Values to oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449544/multiple-scope-values-to-oauth2)

Comment: @PDHide thank you, but no. My question is specific to Postman.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm not pressing return, but separating by spaces instead. The way it looks is due to how Postman is doing the formatting once I add the fields there.

Comment: try following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjCauMywU2Q.  Let me know if it doesnt work and i will give it a go.  I dont have access to classroom but it really should be the same for any api.

Comment: goto console and see how the headers are send for scope in postman @FrancislainyCampos

Comment: @DaImTo the video shows only one scope.

Comment: yes i know can you get it to work with a single scope?

Comment: For requests that only require one scope yes, but this one requires multiple permissions.

Comment: @PDHide I've added the picture of the console

Comment: I just tested it using both google analytics scopes and it works file.  How are you using the access token exactly.

Comment: It's set under the access token field.

Comment: What access token field? Where are you setting it?

Comment: I'm not requesting access tokens. I already have this. I'm trying to get course work from a course item. The access token is set under the access token field at the top of the picture.

Comment: If you look at your picture, the access token is a field at the top. There is where I set mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238274/discussion-between-daimto-and-francislainy-campos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you changed the scopes and forgot to **request a new access token** and click the use token button or are **running on an old access token** prior to requesting additional scopes?

just tested this using both Google analytics scopes.

[image]

as you can see the response gives me an access token containing both scopes that i requested.

[image]

Comment: Where are the multiple scopes?

Comment: better image without the ... There are multiple scopes.   Let me ask you did you change the scopes and forget to request a new access token and click the use token button?  Are you running on an old access token prior to requesting additional scopes?  really this shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I'm not adding extra scopes. These are the ones required by the delete api.

Comment: It's working now, thank you. You're right. I generated a new access token and it worked. Cheers.

Comment: If you'd like to edit your answer I can mark it as accepted as your comment is actually what fixed it and not what is there before that.

Comment: Be my guest. Glad you got it working you were driving me crazy.   It shouldnt be that hard :)   it was why i created the video.  Maybe i should create a new one with two scopes and clicking the button everytime :)